# UsersController in Admin namespace seen as the one defining UsersController?

Tags: namespaces, ruby-on-rails-3, subclass

In rails console I get the following:

> > >> UsersController
> >
> > LoadError: Expected /../app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb to define UsersController

I'm using Rails 3.0.0.rc.
Exact same code works fine for 3.0.0.beta3 and 3.0.0.beta4 BTW.

In short the controllers look like:

app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb

```
class Admin::UsersController < AdminController
...
end
```

app/controllers/admin_controller.rb

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
...
end
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
...
end
```

I've used this Admin stuff many time (haven't we all :) ).. but never got this weird issue.
All files are loaded and this should be straight forward thing. Guess I'm doing smth stupid somewhere :).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just notice your...

> app/controllers/admin/users_contoller.rb

controller is spelled wrong, missing r. I'm guessing that might have been a typo in your post,
but who knows, it's worth to double check because that's usually what the error means.